# how is it possible to design a java based user interface using custom tabbed panes and provide an broswer like design?

Tags: java, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I had started working on a java based tool that my friend has developed. Now we are working on it together. He has used custom made jpanels and used them in jtabed pane like fashion. Its something like this,(check the link for the screen shot,since i am new user,i cannot post images here)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wnrmxiraywlg7p/tab2.png

The problem is that,we want to implement a browser like display of tabs,when the number of tabs opened is more that the panels widths,it gets hided.so the idea is to develop a left and right brows tab buttons tats similar to web broswer .how this could b achieved?

More info about the current layout and design:

The canvas panels are created and tab panels are created and finally called in the main display panel. The stagetab panel holds the tab panels(which mimics appearances of the tabbed pane). Also there already functions to display various canvas panel(different tabs) based on user pressing the tab panels.so all those are working well.  have been looking on various solutions for this problem.one sch is developing an custom view port like method similar to jscroll pane which could be used here.

What would be the better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A good possibility would be to use [SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT) as tabLayoutPolicy. This will show two arrows at the corner of the JTabbedPane. Of course you could redesign the component to show it as you want.

You can find an image of a table using it [here](http://www.javadrive.jp/tutorial/jtabbedpane/img/p9-1.png).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but since he has used  jpanels to form tabs ,(ie) custom made tabs,it is not possible to use the JTabbedPane methods. Else tat design has to be completely changed in order to have JTabbedpane and then use the SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT.Will it be a best solution for the current problem??

Comment: It's a little weird make a new JTabbedPane from scratch insteand of extend Java implementation. I think that you should change it. It's really easy. You only have to create a new JTabbedPane and add JPanels inside.

Comment: Thank you guys, i have worked out an way to have a similar feature like an web browser in the java application.Am new to stack overflow,is there way to close the question ?

Comment: No, you can't close a question because it may be useful for others with a similar problem. The only thing you can do (and is embarrassing because mine is the only answer) is accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask